# Spivak, Calculus, Chapter 1, Problem 19b: where is $2xy\leq x^2+y^2$ derived from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know where the inequality $$2xy\leq x^2+y^2\tag{1}$$ is derived from?

A bit of context: in the Prologue section of Spivak's Calculus, Ch.1 problem 19b, we are asked to prove Schwarz inequality starting from the inequality $$2xy\leq x^2+y^2$$ with
$$x=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$$
$$y=\frac{y_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$$

It is straightforward to do the algebraic manipulations and reach Schwarz Inequality, namely

$$x_1y_1+x_2y_2\leq\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)}$$

In the description of the problem, when it says to use expression $(1)$ there is a question in parentheses: "how is this derived"?

Answer (score 3):

$(x-y)^2\geq 0$, being a square, and since $(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy$ we get the result.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $(x-y)^2\ge0$ since squares are non-negative. Expanding the brackets and rearranging gives $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$.

Answer (score 2):

another one:

You know that the arithmetic mean will be greater than the geometric mean, for any pair of positive values $a$,$b$.

So, let be $x,y$ any non zero real numbers, then $x^2, y^2$ are always positive, so we can apply the previous mean relation between those values:
$$A.M(x^2, y^2) \ge G.M(x^2, y^2)$$
$$\dfrac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \ge \sqrt{x^2\cdot y^2}=|x|\cdot|y|\ge x\cdot y$$

therefore $$2\cdot x\cdot y \le x^2 + y^2$$

Geometrical proof:
[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, assume wlog $x\ge y$, therefore

$$x^2+y^2=x \cdot x+ y\cdot y \ge x \cdot y +x \cdot y=2xy$$

which is known as [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).